# Problem when deploying my GatsbyJS site on netlify

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I use a GatsbyJS template and try to get it deployed on netlify. The site gets deployed but when I try to access it through the webbrowser it is constantly reloaded: https://www.nikolaus-lipusch.com/

The template I use is openly accessible:https://github.com/konstantinmuenster/gatsby-starter-portfolio-minimal-theme

I only changed the content. I suppose I have to change smthg in some sub-folders or config files. Since I am a newbie in this I kindly ask for help.

Kind regards,

Nik